# how can I learn size of geometry for iteration in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to learn count of pixels in my rectangle bound. For example; I should see MxN size of bound.
my codes is :
https://code.earthengine.google.com/11cafc2e8de63293000ee2a3c2036ae4

Comment: I think It is not possible to calculate the pixels here, because it is geometry, not a raster image. The rectangle bound may be calculated for a raster depending upon the pixel size of the raster. So in this case you may calculate the area covered by geometry instead of pixel as https://code.earthengine.google.com/60108742e524bd175eb6ec7178381773

Comment: Thank you,I cliped any image by my bound and I could get size of geometry or image

Comment: That’s what I was saying, pixel size is attribute of raster, can’t be performed over geometry/vectors/shapefiles. @CHH

Comment: yeah you are right. So, How can I apply the image.shape code to the image? When I applied somethings I found (4,16).But this is not make sense

Comment: I have to see that, can you share the URL to the code?

Comment: yeah,Here is my codes:   band_arrs = MclassA2.sampleRectangle(Bound)
band_arr_b4 = band_arrs.get('MNDWI')
np_arr_b4 = np.array(band_arr_b4.getInfo())
print(np_arr_b4.shape) .........................and result is (4,16)

Comment: It would be more understandable if you add the link/URL, like you have added in your question.

Comment: I am working in Colab. So I do not know how to share any url

Comment: Ohh okay, I don’t know much of python API of GEE though, I’ll try if I found any solution 